# Use htaccess to redirect the current subfolder to a sub-subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all traffic to http://example.com/sub1 to http://example.com/sub1/sub2/. The htaccess file lives at http://example.com/sub1

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/sub1/.htaccess` use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!sub2/).*) sub2/$1 [L,NC]
```

If you want full redirect (URL to change in browser) then use:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!sub2/).*) sub2/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```